# What is the function of のかも in a question sentence like this

Tags: particle-の, particle-が, particle-も

> エリートにも まだまだ解らない事が あるものです,
> 何故アナタがまだ 私を見捨てずにそこで 戦い続けているのかも,
> 何故 私がそこに向かおうと しているのかも

What is the function of のかも in this sentence?

の can act as explanatory particle and かも can be translated into "might be". のかも when placed at end of sentence usually means something like "this might be because..." but considering the sentence is a wh-question I don't think this meaning applies here.

のか here might actually show that the clause preceding it is a noun and も here acts like a function to list things, but I have never seen も is placed on the end of sentence so I am quite unsure about this.

Note: I got this sentence from a manga and the "," in this sentence doesn't actually exist, I just placed it there to show where the sentence is separated.

Comment: The bold part is left unspoken: エリートにも まだまだ解らない事が あるものです, 何故アナタがまだ 私を見捨てずにそこで 戦い続けているのかも, 何故 私がそこに向かおうと しているのかも**わかりません**

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the confusion is that these are not actually technically questions.  They are "unknowns" being used in a statement:

> エリートにも まだまだ解らない事が あるものです, 何故アナタがまだ 私を見捨てずにそこで 戦い続けているのかも, 何故 私がそこに向かおうと しているのかも
> Even as an elite, there are still things I don't understand, both why you haven't given up and are still fighting for me, and why I'm heading there.

These "why"s are not actually questions of the listener to answer.  They are simply statements of things the speaker does not know.  The か particle can also be used for this purpose within a sentence, to mark a phrase as something "unknown" that is being referenced, for example:

> **なぜそうしたのか**を考えています。
> I'm thinking about **why he did it**.

The other thing to notice is there are actually two of these unknowns being stated:

> 何故アナタがまだ 私を見捨てずにそこで 戦い続けているのか -- "why you haven't given up and are still fighting for me"
> 何故 私がそこに向かおうと しているのか -- "why I'm heading there"

These two things are then being connected using the AもBも construction to say "both A and B".

So these のかもs are actually three different particles.  の turns the verb phrase into a noun, か marks it as an unknown thing or "open question", and も..も is then being used to connect the two things together as a single subject/topic.

This last part of things is, of course, an incomplete sentence.  To be a complete sentence, you could add something like「解らない事です」("..are things I don't understand") on the end, but the meaning is pretty obvious from context even without it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

エリートにも まだまだ解らない事が あるものです, 何故アナタがまだ 私を見捨てずにそこで 戦い続けているのかも(解らない), 何故 私がそこに向かおうと しているのかも(解らない). From this sentence, it feels not only this two things, but there are so many things to 解らない事.